# Развертование Web-Service

Tags: java, развертывание, веб-служба

Имеется Web-Service написанный на Java с помощью Spring Framework, подскажите бесплатный хостинг где можно развернуть его и как правильно это сделать?
Где Вы разворачиваете свои Web-Service?

Answer (score 1):

С пошаговой инструкцией деплой в несколько шагов:

https://www.heroku.com/java

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться серверами Amazon'a. Они на год дают сервер в бесплатное пользование.